# Changing the output of a javascript

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have this (part of a) script that sends events to Analytics depending on the time settings. By default it sends event every 10 seconds and the output is ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", "0:10") and 10 seconds later it is ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", "0:20").

What I can't figure out is when I change the time settings to fire an event every 20 seconds how to get this output ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", "0:20") and the next one 20 seconds later ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", "0:40").

This is the code I have

```
var stLogInterval = 20;

function TrackingLogTime(tosArray) {
    return tosArray[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(tosArray[1]) + 1) + ":00" : (tosArray[1] || "0") + ":" + (parseInt(tosArray[0]) + 10 )
}

function stInitializeControlVars() {
    if (typeof window.stLogInterval == "undefined") {
        window.stLogInterval = 10000
    }
}

function startTimeTracking(tos) {
    stInitializeControlVars();
    window.stIntervalObj = window.setInterval(function() {
        total_time += 10;
        tos = TrackingLogTime(tos.split(":").reverse());
        ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos)
    }, (window.stLogInterval))
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    startTimeTracking("00")
})
```

Is there a way to add the stLogInterval to the TrackingLogTime? I have tried to just replace + 10 with + stLogInterval but that didn't do the job.

Comment: do you want time to be displayed with minutes, hours? i.e. `0:20`, `0:40`, `1:00` etc.?

Comment: The way it is now are seconds. So 0:20 is 20 seconds although I agree it looks like minutes. The output should just be 0:20 and 0:40 etc. Thanks

Comment: I understand that the last part is seconds, is it acceptable to get 0:100 instead of 1:40  ?

Comment: though I suppose that is not acceptable

Comment: No, it's not possible. I'm afraid it will mess with my previous data in Analytics.

Comment: So you want 1:40, right? I mean, the minutes, hours to be correctly updated too, not just adding 20 seconds each step

Comment: 1:40 means 1 minute and 40 seconds. The script works like this: every 10 seconds (depending on the input) the script sends an event to Analytics with the time as the label. In this case someone is still online after 1 minute and 40 secs.

Comment: The steps (seconds) are depending on the input (stLogInterval)

Comment: what I'm asking is to clarify what do you want. I ran this code with a slightest modification locally and it works, it produces "0:20", "0:40", "0:60", "0:80", "0:100" etc. And I want to know whether this is what you want. I just don't want to look deeper if there is no need for this.

Comment: Got it. Yes I want 1:40 and not 0:100.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this line

```
return tosArray[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(tosArray[1]) + 1) + ":00" : (tosArray[1] || "0") + ":" + (parseInt(tosArray[0]) + 10 )
```

to this one

```
return tosArray[0] == 40 ? (parseInt(tosArray[1]) + 1) + ":00" : (tosArray[1] || "0") + ":" + (parseInt(tosArray[0]) + 20 )
```

and `window.stLogInterval = 10000` to `window.stLogInterval = 20000`

=======================================================================
Additional notes are:

Also I want to warn you that this is not safe to rely on javascript timers because js is single threaded and code you expect to call exactly after a timeout or interval passed can be called much more later. Though with interval of 20 sec I don't think this would be the issue.

And by the way there are some mess in your code. This line seems to be useless

```
total_time += 10;
```

Also this `var stLogInterval = 20;` and this

```
if (typeof window.stLogInterval == "undefined") {
    window.stLogInterval = 10000
}
```

is nonsense. You need to use variable or the window property exclusively, not both, preferably variable

========================

**update according to the comments**

you need to change function TrackingLogTime to

```
function TrackingLogTime(tosArray) {
    var minPart;
    var sec = +tosArray[0] + 20;
    if (sec >= 60) {
        minPart = +tosArray[1] + 1;
        sec -= 60;
    } else {
        minPart = tosArray[1] || '0';
    }
    sec = sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec;
    return minPart + ':' + sec;
}
```

and `window.stLogInterval = 20000` must be set instead of 10000. I really don't like this function, it is a bit not logical, but these are the minor changes required.

Comment: Thanks. The mess in the code is probably useful for some other part of the code. I only took out the part that I needed for this question.

People can actually set the time variable themselves. How about if they set the variable to 30 seconds? I understand the above is working when I change it manually, but if someone changes the time variable on a plugin options page the output should also be accordingly.

Comment: @WendiT so then you might need to change `total_time += 10` to += 20 accordingly

Comment: Do I understand it correctly when I say that the 50 and 10 and 40 and 20 are the seconds to make the minute? And the 10 and 20 are the steps to take?

Comment: @WendiT 10 and 20 ( I think you're asking about `total_time += 10;` and `total_time += 20;` ) I don't know what it is. I can guess that 10 and 20 a seconds and this variable is used somewhere else. As for 50 and 10 and 40 and 20, this logic takes your previous time string, for instance `1:40` splits it to an Array and reverts it, so you get `[40:1]` and then checks if you have 40, it adds 1 to the minute value and set seconds value to 0. So, yes, you are right, these are seconds

Comment: Yes, the total_time is needed for another function. Could you still look at the 5th comment about this one: People can actually set the time variable themselves. How about if they set the variable to 30 seconds? I understand the above is working when I change it manually, but if someone changes the time variable on a plugin options page the output should also be accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82353/discussion-between-user907860-and-wendit).

Comment: user907860, is it possible to contact you by mail over this? I still want to change this, but it's way over my head...

Comment: @WendiT, if you still need this you can contact me at d.koroliov on gmail.com